# Why would an outer div not expand to the width of its contents?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have following div structure in a part of my page. When the page renders, I see that `contentDiv` has less width than the `texArea` element. When I looked up the elements in Chrome's developer tool, `contentDiv` had a width of 239px even though`textArea` had a width of 550px.

**Question**: Why would an outer div not take the width of its contents, when the outer div has no style mentioned for width and height, and how would I make sure that outer div was always greater than inner div dimensions?

```
<div id="contentDiv">
 <asp:Label ID="lblCodeType" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
   <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" Width="550" Height="500" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="consolas,sans-serif"></asp:TextBox>
       <div id="runCode" style="width:80%"">
                    <input type="button" value="Run above code" onclick="runCode(); return false;" id="btnRunCode" /><br />
                    (NOTE: Uncomment the code that you want to run, and comment what you don't want to run. DO NOT run multiple popup code at the same time; for example do not uncomment radalert as well as radconfirm code before running the code, but only have either radalert or radconfirm uncommented.)
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1**

The CSS for the parent of the outer div is as below.

```
element.style {
    height: 516.667px;
}
div#radWindow1_C {
}
.RadWindow_MetroTouch .rwContent {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}
.RadWindow .rwContent {
    padding: .41667em .83333em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After some research I came up with 2 solutions. I couldn't figure out why CSS behaved this way (probably because of a complex application of many CSS rules coming from other elements/divs in this ASP.Net page) , but either of these two solutions solved my problem.

*Solution 1*: `contentDiv` needs to be displayed like a table or table-row or table-cell i.e. `display` CSS attribute needs to be either `table` or `table-row` or `table-cell`.

```
<div id="contentDiv" style="display:table">
 <asp:Label ID="lblCodeType" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
   <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" Width="550" Height="500" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="consolas,sans-serif"></asp:TextBox>
       <div id="runCode" style="width:80%"">
                    <input type="button" value="Run above code" onclick="runCode(); return false;" id="btnRunCode" /><br />
                    (NOTE: Uncomment the code that you want to run, and comment what you don't want to run. DO NOT run multiple popup code at the same time; for example do not uncomment radalert as well as radconfirm code before running the code, but only have either radalert or radconfirm uncommented.)
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Solution 2* : Using JavaScript and/or jquery, all descendants at all DOM levels of `contentDiv` need to be parsed for width and height so that max width and max height among its descendants can be determined. Then we just need to set the width and height of `contentDiv` to these max values plus some margin.  This is shown in code below.

```
function pageLoad() {
            var max_width = 0;
            var max_height = 0;
            var element_width = 0;
            var element_height = 0;
               $("#contentDiv").find("*").each(function () {
                    element_width = parseInt($(this).width());
                    if (element_width > max_width) {
                        max_width = element_width;
                    }
                    element_height = parseInt($(this).height());
                    if (element_height > max_height) {
                        max_height = element_height;
                    }
                });
               if ($("#contentDiv").width() < max_width) {
                   $("#contentDiv").width(max_width + 10);
               }
               if ($("#contentDiv").height() < max_height) {
                   $("#contentDiv").height(max_height + 10);
               }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your css? Cant tell much with just the html.

Comment: There is no CSS for outer div as its without any styling applied at design-time, and that is why I was surprised at the results.

Comment: What about the parent of the outer div and the rest of the document? It's all relevant.

Comment: This is part of a complex page, but I have posted the styles applied to parent of the `contentDiv`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there is some parent element with a set width:

```html
<div style="width: 280px;">
  <div>
    This div has a width of only 280px, even without having any style vinculated.
    <textarea style="width: 550px"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the outer div has no style of width: 280px, does the div auto-expand?

Comment: May be the guaranteed approach here is to use JavaScript to get the outer div and then find the max width of all its children/grand children/... The outer div can then be given this max width plus some padding.

Comment: If any parent of the outer div has a width set, the inner divs that don't have width set will assume that parent div's width. If none of parent elements have width set, the inner div will have 100% in width.

Comment: Ok. I will need to look and find if there is some outer div causing this. Thanks. I will let you know what I find.

Comment: One more thing, when I style contentDiv with style="display:table-cell", then it works magically and outer div is never smaller than its contents. But why should this style solve this issue or appear to?

Comment: May be a table cell always makes sure that its contents fit into it? Even style="display:table" makes it work magically.

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .parent {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .center {
      background-color: #00FF00;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="center"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please find the best example for displaying child div to the parent div.